# Is there any way to recompile binaries from x86 to ARM on linux?

Tags: linux, compilation, x86, arm

I'd like to collect some ideas about the solution of following problem.
I've got a TOF camera, and its driver for linux x86/64. It works fine. But in fact the camera would be used on an ARM based embedded device if that's possible.

Questions:

- should I have to decompile the driver binaries and recompile with ARM compiler? is there any available decompiler tool?
- is there any ARM>>x86 emulator which is available?
- any other ideas?

ps: the pure source is very expensive, so I don't like to purchase it anyway :)

Comment: The title of your question can effectively be read as "Can I run x86 binaries on an ARM device?" and answer to that is "no". You can reverse engineer the driver, that's it.

Answer (score 4):

1. AFAIK, as of today, there's no such decompiler that will generate compilable code from machine code. You will have to manually fix (usually a LOT of fixes) the generated code. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193896/whats-a-good-c-decompiler) question for Linux decompilers.
2. Check [QEmu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page). Underlying architecture is not relevant as long as you can execute it ;)
3. There's not much besides what you've stated.

What you're attempting is (in part) [reverse engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering). RE is a complex process and requires great knowledge in the *thing* you're attempting to reverse; in your case camera drivers. If you have knowledge in this area, go ahead. If you don't, I wouldn't waste my time on it (or get the knowledge first ;))

Answer (score 0):

See the following answer for details. It lists some of the problems you could encounter attempting to automate such a translation:

[Convert object file to another architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091579/convert-object-file-to-another-architecture/14114498#14114498)

Answer (score 0):

Recently created [Eltechs ExaGear Server](http://www.prlog.org/12200999-bios-it-boston-and-eltechs-bring-x86-apps-to-arm-as-service-cloud-platform.html), available on [ARM as A Service](http://www.armasaservice.com/), runs x86 applications on ARM devices.

It is new and proprietary, but it does exist.

Answer (score 0):

If your driver is a kernel object, there is no emulator (to my knowledge) capable of running x86 kernel code inside ARM kernel. If your "driver" is in fact a userspace library hacked on top of a generic driver (v4l2, etc.), you may have luck with QEMU or Exagear mentioned here. As a side note, you will probably end up with an x86 application software, too, as calling an x86 library from ARM code is not supported by QEMU or Exagear out of the box.